# ROM = PRP and Public Random beacon/CRS?

Tags: random-oracle-model

I am trying to understand how different assumptions might relate to each other and if they are absolute different or if they can be reduced to each other.

- Can the random oracle be substituted with a PRP with a CRS?
- Can a PRP construction with a CRS be substituted with a trusted random beacon?
- is the random oracle a theoretical construction for a public random beacon?

Comment: At a cursory glance the well known result of [Canetti, Goldreich, and Halevi](https://eprint.iacr.org/1998/011.pdf) should be unaffected by the existence of a CRS. As such the answer to your first point should be **no**. I don't quite understand your other questions.